# File I/O error with getline()

Tags: c++

My code:

```
void listall()
{
    string line;
    ifstream input;
    input.open("registry.txt", ios::in);

    if(input.is_open())
    {
        while(std::getline(input, line, "\n"))
        {
            cout<<line<<"\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Error opening file.\n";
    }
}
```

I’m new to C++, and I want to print out a text file line-by-line. I’m using Code::Blocks.

The error it gives me is:

> error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, std::string&, const char [2])'

Comment: Have you tried looking at a reference for it? You'd find a type mismatch in that and the error messages, and the fact that the default delimiter is a newline.

Comment: Try putting the newline in single quotes in the call to getline. It takes a char, not a string. And make sure you #include <iostream> and #include <string>.

Comment: @aet Thanks, that actually worked. Shouldve known that it was trying to tell me that it wanted a char, if i *tried* to analyze it just a little more i probably couldve figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the valid overloads for `std::getline`:

```
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str);
```

I'm sure you meant `std::getline(input, line, '\n')`

`"\n"` is not a character, it's an array of characters with a size of 2 (1 for the `'\n'` and another for the NUL-terminator `'\0'`).

Comment: I saw aet's comment first, his (or hers) fix worked. However you stated the same thing, so ive got to give you credit. Resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```
#include <fstream>    // for std::ffstream
#include <iostream>   // for std::cout
#include <string>     // for std::string and std::getline

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("registry.txt");

    for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line); ) 
    {
         std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
}
```

If you want the error check, it is something like this:

```
if (!input) { std::cerr << "Could not open file.\n"; }
```

Comment: What does std::cerr do?

Comment: @user2597522 there's the standard out stream which can be written to with `std::cout` and the standard error stream which can be written to with `std::cerr`.  It is advisable to write error the `std::cerr` so that you can distinguish between normal program flow and error messages when running.  For example `./a.out > /dev/null` will throw away everything written to standard out.  `./a.out 2 > errors.txt` will write all erorr text to "errors.txt"